# Principal value of Fourier Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have tried to find the principal value of

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\sin(2x)\over x^3}\,dx.$$

As $ {\sin(2x)\over x^3}$ is an even function, its integral may not be zero in the given limits. I cannot calculate its principal value as I met with a third order pole at $z=0$. The expected value is $-2\pi$. How can I compute the principal value?

Comment: What's the problem? Just use contour integration.

Comment: Also, how is this a Fourier integral?

Answer (score 1):

For this you want to use the function

$$f(z)={e^{2iz}\over z^3}$$

then use the fact that $\sin(2z)=\Im( e^{2iz})$ on the real axis. The exponential has the right decay for a semicircular contour with a bump around the origin, that's why we choose it.

Now, since we only go halfway around, we get only half the residue

> $${1\over 2}\operatorname{Res}\left({e^{2iz}\over z^3},0\right)={1\over 2\pi i}\int_C {e^{2iz}\over z^3}\,dz$$

and taking imaginary parts of this we get

$$PV\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\sin(2x)\over x^3}\,dx\right)$$

The last equality with our original integral comes from the fact that cosine part goes to $0$ since ${\cos(2z)\over z^3}$ is an odd function, so the PV is $0$.

The contour is made up of pieces in the form

> $$C=[-R,-\epsilon]\cup C_\epsilon\cup [\epsilon, R]\cup C_R$$

where the $C_r$ are semicircles of radius $r$ centered at the origin and in the upper half plane, the $\epsilon$ circle is clockwise to agree with the direction of the contour traveling from $-R\to\epsilon$ and then the next segment $\epsilon\to R$, the $R$ circle is counter-clockwise aimed to connect the two segments who's ends are distance $R$ from the origin. The circular integrals go to $0$ by the standard estimates, so all we will be left with in the limit will be

$$PV\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\sin(2x)\over x^3}\,dx\right).$$

Computing the residue we see this is ${1\over 2!}{d^2\over dz^2}\bigg|_{z=0}\left(e^{2iz}\right)=-2$, hence we get that the value of the integral is

$$-{2\pi i\over 2}\cdot 2$$

and since the sine portion is the imaginary part, we see that our original integral is just $-2\pi$, as desired.

Comment: Please show me the proof of  ${1\over 2}\operatorname{Res}\left({e^{2iz}\over z^3},0\right)={1\over 2\pi i}\int_C {e^{2iz}\over z^3}\,dz$.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 this is just the argument principle, since you're going around the residue half-way, you get half the residue.

Comment: The graph of $y=\sin(2x)/x^3$ suggests that $PV\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\sin(2x)\over x^3}\,dx\right)$ is positive (if $PV\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\sin(2x)\over x^3}\,dx\right)$ exists).

Comment: To be precise, what is computed is the finite part of the integral. The Cauchy principal value doesn't exist:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left(
 \int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} + \int_\epsilon^\infty \right)
  \frac {\sin 2 x} {x^3} dx = \infty$$
because $\sin(2 x)/x^3$ behaves as $1/x^2$ at zero.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Cant really understand how did you come up with the expression of residue for $\frac{\exp(iz)}{z^3}$. Since the function has a pole of order 3; and if we traverse the contour $C_r$ clockwise over the singularity at $z=0$, then in the limit $r \rightarrow 0$, the $a_{-3}, a_{-2}$ terms diverge.

Comment: On hindsight I was thinking specifically about $CIT$. Since, $\exp(2iz)$ is an entire function, and the singularity $0$ is within the small semicircle traversed clockwise; so one can evaluate the integral, but the answer is just half of the original, since one traverses half of it. That gets the job done. Albeit one has to carry over the negative sign for going in the clockwise direction.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately $$PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\sin 2x\over x^3}\,dx$$ diverges.
The integrals $\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^{\infty} {\sin 2x\over x^3}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}{\sin 2x\over x^3}\,dx$ exist.
Since $$\sin 2x\ge \frac{4}{\pi}x$$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$, we have $$\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3}\ge \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^2} $$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$. Thus $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{-\epsilon} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} dx=\int_\epsilon^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} dx\ge \int_\epsilon^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\frac{4}{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\frac{4}{\pi}\right).$$ 
Therefore $$PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} dx =\lim_{ \epsilon\to 0} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}
 +\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{-\epsilon}  +\int_\epsilon^{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^{\infty}\right) {\sin 2x\over x^3}\,dx=+\infty.$$

Comment: I agree with you. +1.